# Editor.isDirty() broken?

Tags: tinymce, javascript

The Editor.isDirty() does not seem to be working correctly. In our application we check the Editor.isDirty() flag. When it evaluates to true we need to move forward with some actions. If nothing has changed we don't want to waste processor time evaluating data that hasn't changed. In our case once the content is updated once isDirty() always evaluates to true. Even when nothing has changed.

The Editor.isDirty() function seems pretty simple:

```
isDirty : function() {
  var self = this;
  return tinymce.trim(self.startContent) != tinymce.trim(self.getContent({format : 'raw', no_events : 1})) && !self.isNotDirty;
}
```

The key seems to be the startContent property. That's what TinyMCE uses to determine a change has occured. Therefore I would expect this property to be updated when save() is called on the Editor. Looking through the code shows this does not happen. In fact startContent does is not reset anywhere which would support it's use here. Has anyone else seen this behavior, or am I using the Editor object incorrectly?

sidenote: TinyMCE version 3.5.7.

Comment: I am seeing this issue as well.  I've done a character count on the textarea before tinyMCE initialization and after.  Based on my settings, the character count is off by the number of paragraph tags at the root level of the content.

Comment: I'm seeing this in 2019.  Any resolution?